# My button is not moving centre of the page?

Tags: html, css

I have one page in that page left side bottom of the page one floating button is there i want to move that button left side centre of the page with fixed position ,i tried with marging-top but it's not working, can you please help me to achieve this thing

```css
#cbtn{
    position:fixed;
    margin-top: -200px;
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    bottom:20px;
    /* right:40px; */
    background-color:#5468ff;
    color:white;
    border-radius:50px;
    text-align:center;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #999;
}
```

```html
<table id="cbtn" >
  <tr  onclick="window.open('tel:7204968541');">
    <td>
      <a href="#" class="btn-xl" onclick="window.open('tel:7204968541');"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-telephone" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M3.654 1.328a.678.678 0 0 0-1.015-.063L1.605 2.3c-.483.484-.661 1.169-.45 1.77a17.568 17.568 0 0 0 4.168 6.608 17.569 17.569 0 0 0 6.608 4.168c.601.211 1.286.033 1.77-.45l1.034-1.034a.678.678 0 0 0-.063-1.015l-2.307-1.794a.678.678 0 0 0-.58-.122l-2.19.547a1.745 1.745 0 0 1-1.657-.459L5.482 8.062a1.745 1.745 0 0 1-.46-1.657l.548-2.19a.678.678 0 0 0-.122-.58L3.654 1.328zM1.884.511a1.745 1.745 0 0 1 2.612.163L6.29 2.98c.329.423.445.974.315 1.494l-.547 2.19a.678.678 0 0 0 .178.643l2.457 2.457a.678.678 0 0 0 .644.178l2.189-.547a1.745 1.745 0 0 1 1.494.315l2.306 1.794c.829.645.905 1.87.163 2.611l-1.034 1.034c-.74.74-1.846 1.065-2.877.702a18.634 18.634 0 0 1-7.01-4.42 18.634 18.634 0 0 1-4.42-7.009c-.362-1.03-.037-2.137.703-2.877L1.885.511z"/>
</svg></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if i understood you correctly, but here is an example on how you can center the button on the page.

1. You can give it a `top: 50%`. This will plage the button's left side on the center of the page.
2. Then we add `transform: translateY(-50%)` to move it left by 50% of its width, which makes it perfectly centered on the page

```css
#cbtn {
  position: fixed;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background-color: #5468ff;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #999;
}
```

```html
<table id="cbtn">
  <tr onclick="window.open('tel:7204968541');">
    <td>
      <a href="#" class="btn-xl" onclick="window.open('tel:7204968541');"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-telephone" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M3.654 1.328a.678.678 0 0 0-1.015-.063L1.605 2.3c-.483.484-.661 1.169-.45 1.77a17.568 17.568 0 0 0 4.168 6.608 17.569 17.569 0 0 0 6.608 4.168c.601.211 1.286.033 1.77-.45l1.034-1.034a.678.678 0 0 0-.063-1.015l-2.307-1.794a.678.678 0 0 0-.58-.122l-2.19.547a1.745 1.745 0 0 1-1.657-.459L5.482 8.062a1.745 1.745 0 0 1-.46-1.657l.548-2.19a.678.678 0 0 0-.122-.58L3.654 1.328zM1.884.511a1.745 1.745 0 0 1 2.612.163L6.29 2.98c.329.423.445.974.315 1.494l-.547 2.19a.678.678 0 0 0 .178.643l2.457 2.457a.678.678 0 0 0 .644.178l2.189-.547a1.745 1.745 0 0 1 1.494.315l2.306 1.794c.829.645.905 1.87.163 2.611l-1.034 1.034c-.74.74-1.846 1.065-2.877.702a18.634 18.634 0 0 1-7.01-4.42 18.634 18.634 0 0 1-4.42-7.009c-.362-1.03-.037-2.137.703-2.877L1.885.511z"/>
</svg></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Your markup seems a bit strange.
maybe you could simple have a `<a href="tel:123-456-7890">...</a>`. This will call the number when people click on it. no need to add extra markup and onclick events...

Comment: not centre of the page centre of the left side of the page

Comment: @saisai I have changed it so it is half way down the page on the left side. Is this what you mean? If not, maybe you should add an image to show us what you want to do

Comment: exactly centre of the page  of left side

Comment: not like the example i changed for you? sorry, but i am not sure what you mean...

Comment: @Boguz your div is not vertically centered. remove the `margin-top` and try `top:50%` with `transform: translateY(-50%);` or `bottom:50%` with `transform: translateY(50%);`

Comment: @Cédric yes, of course you are right, i didn't notice the margin-top. it is fixed! thanks

Answer (score 1):

I used  `position:fixed;`, `top:50%;` and `transform: translateY(-50%);`

I simplified the html by using a link tag.

I centered the icon with `display:flex;`, `align-items:center;` `justify-content:center;`

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
}

.call {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #5468ff;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #999;
  
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<a href="tel:7204968541" class="call">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-telephone" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path d="M3.654 1.328a.678.678 0 0 0-1.015-.063L1.605 2.3c-.483.484-.661 1.169-.45 1.77a17.568 17.568 0 0 0 4.168 6.608 17.569 17.569 0 0 0 6.608 4.168c.601.211 1.286.033 1.77-.45l1.034-1.034a.678.678 0 0 0-.063-1.015l-2.307-1.794a.678.678 0 0 0-.58-.122l-2.19.547a1.745 1.745 0 0 1-1.657-.459L5.482 8.062a1.745 1.745 0 0 1-.46-1.657l.548-2.19a.678.678 0 0 0-.122-.58L3.654 1.328zM1.884.511a1.745 1.745 0 0 1 2.612.163L6.29 2.98c.329.423.445.974.315 1.494l-.547 2.19a.678.678 0 0 0 .178.643l2.457 2.457a.678.678 0 0 0 .644.178l2.189-.547a1.745 1.745 0 0 1 1.494.315l2.306 1.794c.829.645.905 1.87.163 2.611l-1.034 1.034c-.74.74-1.846 1.065-2.877.702a18.634 18.634 0 0 1-7.01-4.42 18.634 18.634 0 0 1-4.42-7.009c-.362-1.03-.037-2.137.703-2.877L1.885.511z"/></svg>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use flex for this what you can do is...

apply flex CSS to telephone's parent and write:

```
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
```

this will work to make element center
you can refer this link it will help you: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-center-a-div-using-flexbox-property-of-css/